# Draw bottom line in a TextView eactly the same as that appearing in EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have an activity screen that is organized, let me say... in some rows and two columns.
This activity is used to request user information.

For example:

```
Name            <EditText for enter name>
Address         <EditText for enter address>
City            <EditText for enter city>
AnotherFIeld     <TextView>
```

The EditText widgets display a line at the bottom, and all are the same length. So what I want is exactly the same for TextView, that is, I would like to display the same line at its bottom, exactly the same (color, lenght, widht...). Also I need TextView to have the same look (height, widht, ...)

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are expecting your TextView to look exactly like, I assume that you are choosing TextView because it should be read only.

It is better to use the editText itself for "AnotherFIeld" also, with property read-only. So your requirement will be met.

Comment: Yes, I need textview to be readonly but with the look of edittext. Finally I have used an edittext and set its focusable property from xml to false.